# Is it possible to ask R to run a separate script/rmd/project file before running the current codes?

Tags: r, rstudio

For example, my data cleaning codes are stored as File A as a script/rmd/project file. Now, I am writing File B, which are codes to do some data analysis. Rather than opening File A, running the whole thing, and then coming back to File B, is there a way I can code at the very beginning of File B saying something like, run File A in this directory? Or something similar to this.

Comment: `source("path/to/file A.R")`. Though not sure *exactly* what you mean by "script/rmd/project file", those are 3 different file types. `source()` runs `.R` files. `render` runs  `.Rmd` files. Project files aren't really runnable.